# Problem with MySQL updating a Foreign Key Where the Inner Join is Based on that same Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys

I have a table (`Staff`) with columns of `StaffId` (PK), `StaffName` and `StaffLocationId`. `LocationId` is the foreign key to the `Locations` table. The `Locations` table has columns `LocId` (PK) and `LocName`.

In the `Location` table there are 2 locations with `Id's` of 1 and 2, and `LocNames` of London and Sydney respectively.

Alice is the name off a staff member, and her location Id is 1 (London). I want to move her to Sydney by updating her LocationId to 2 without having access to the Id directly. Obviously I can just do

```
UPDATE Staff 
SET StfLocationId = 2 
WHERE StaffName = 'Alice'
```

but I only have the name Sydney, not the `Id` of 2.

I would assume this is a perfectly normal and easy thing to do, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it is not working.

My latest attempt so far is:

```
UPDATE Staff AS S 
INNER JOIN Locations As L ON L.LocId = S.StfLocationId 
SET S.StfLocationId = L.LocId 
WHERE L.StfLocName = 'Sydney' AND S.StaffName = 'Alice'
```

I would be really grateful if anyone knows the answer to this, I've spent a long time trying various version, using aliases etc all without luck.

Comment: It should be `INNER JOIN Location AS L`. You join with a table name, not a column name.

Comment: You also seem to be all mixed up about the column names. You say that `LocationId` is the FK, but that's not one of the column names you listed before that. Is it `LocationId`, `StfLocationId`, or `StaffLocationId`?

Comment: Sorry Barmar, yes you are correct, this is an error in my simplification from the real scenario. It should have been INNER Join Locations As L. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using an `INNER JOIN`, you should use `CROSS JOIN`, since this is not using the relationship between the two tables.

```
UPDATE Staff AS s
CROSS JOIN Location AS L
SET s.StfLocationId = L.LocId
WHERE s.StaffName = 'Alice' AND l.StfLocName = 'Sydney'
```

You can also use a subquery:

```
UPDATE Staff
SET StfLocationId = (
    SELECT LocId
    FROM Location
    WHERE StfLocName = 'Sydney'
)
WHERE StaffName = 'Alice'
```